# Hair Direction in Cycles ParticleSystem

Tags: particles

I am trying to get hair to come from one side of my plane but it is being emitted from both.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your particle settings or a .blend? Without more info it's hard to say what cause is.

Comment: You can upload a blend e.g. using a service like: pasteall.org/blend/ and add the link here.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer below as accepted

Answer (score 2):

The object origin of the cylinder is used as the emission point. In your .blend,  the origin of the cylinder is in its center, so each particle instance of the cylinder is exactly half on the top and half on the bottom.

To set the origin to one end:

1. Select the cylinder and enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Select one end of it and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Cursor to selected*:

   [image]
3. Exit edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> Origin to 3D cursor*:

   [image]

Comment: I will never call you a conjurer of cheap tricks. Thanks!

Comment: @Anarchitect If this answered your question, feel free to [mark it as accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) :)